# Function with Completion in Timer Selector

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am declaring a function as such:

```
@objc func fetchDatabase(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

I'm allowing the completion to be `nil` so I can either call it as `fetchDatabase()` or as

```
fetchDatabase(completion: { (result) in
    // Stuff in here
})
```

However, I am also trying to use this function in a `#selector` for a `Timer`. I am creating this timer using the following line:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(fetchDatabase), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Without the completion, this runs fine. However, with the completion added, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error whenever the timer is run. Some help with correctly constructing this selector would be greatly appreciated, if this is in fact the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector passed to the timer only allows one of two possible signatures

1. `someFunction()`
2. `someFunction(someLabel someParameter: Timer)`

You can't pass your `fetchDatabase(completion:)` function because it doesn't match either of the two legal selector signatures.

You need to pass a valid selector which in turn calls your `fetchDatabase(completion:)` function. For example:

```
@objc timerHandler() {
    fetchDatabase(completion: { (result) in
        // Stuff in here
    })
}
```

use `#selector(timerHandler)` with your timer.

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments get applied at the calling site, so you'll need to generate two separate methods (one of which calls the other):

```
func fetchDatabase() { fetchDatabase(callback:nil) }

func fetchDatabase(callback:()->()) {
    ...
}
```

Now your `scheduledTimer` call should work fine.